# how to get data if value not exist in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

excuse me anyone can help me??

i try to get data with condition and how to get data if value not same after condition, and this is my data.

```
car
[
0:{
  id: 1,
  subcar:[
    0:{id_car:1},
    1:{id_car:2}
  ]
}];

owner
[
0:{
  id:1,
  id_car:1
},
1:{
  id:2,
  id_car:2
},
2:{
  id:3,
  id_car:3
}];
```

and down here is condition code **UPDATE**

```
example 

`app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

         function cars(){
           $http.get('api/car').then(function(car){

             for(var i = 0; i < car.length; i++)
              {
                var car1 = car[i].subcar;
                for (var j=0; j< car1.length; j++){
                     $scope.car2 = car1[j].id_car;
                }
              }
           });
          }; cars();

         function owners(){
           $http.get('api/owner').then(function(owner){

           for(var i = 0; i < owner.length; i++)
            {
                var owner1 = owner[i].id_car;
                if (owner1 === $scope.car2){
                    //theen he must get data id_car:3 not exist????
                }
            }

           });
        };owners();
});
```

so how to get data `id_car:3` after condition in function owners??
thanks

Comment: It seems odd to declare functions and then immediately call them, espceially on the same line like that. These functions don't return anything, and the first one seems to create a variable that then gets thrown away.

Comment: hmm i dont know about the function, but in my code the function goes well, function will run after controller in call then if i call "car2" from function cars he called car2.
and i dont know how to create a variable that then gets thrown away.
sorry for my language,.

Comment: `var car = car;` so `car` will equal `undefined`..

Comment: @jfriend00 hmmm So, here it is, i have data from json and i success call the data with function,   `function cars for call data and var car = car  -> i mean its example call from from json`,.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok done for update sorry my bad

Comment: Still unclear what you're trying to do.  I just don't understand.

Comment: @jfriend00 hmmmm maybe more simplenya like this, wait?

Comment: @jfriend00 more simple in plunk sorry [plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/mY9l86zkt7jOhKe7fZIW/)

Answer (score 0):

You are making 2 ajax calls, where the callback of the second call relies on data from the first call.

AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning they run in the background while your code continues to execute.  The owners call happens straight after the cars call, while the cars request is still running.  It's mostly unpredictable which call will return first.

You need to change your logic to execute your ajax calls in a promise chain, and then do your processing after wards.

```
function getCarsData() {
    return $http.get('api/car');  // this returns a promise, resolved when the ajax call returns
}

function getOwnersData() {
    return $http.get('api/owners');
}

$q.all([getCarsData(), getOwnersData()]).then(function (results) {
    var car_data = results[0];
    var owner_data = results[1];
    // you can do your logic here
});
```

$q.all takes an array of promises (returned from the ajax calls), and returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises are resolved, passing the resolve values as an array to the then callback.

You probably want to do some error checking, etc. as well.

Comment: hey thanks @fluoresce but i need how to catch data like this [plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/N7Y3QduqE2SYTFhT20iL/)

Comment: thats a different question and you should post it separately.  maybe explain what you are actually trying to acheive.  Your logic is a bit unclear.  You are always setting $scope.car1 equal to the last item in the cars array, so thats the only one that your owners loop will ever match.

Comment: oh in the plunk, sorry i just mean explain it with a simpler code, but my question above refers to the data that is in plunker.

Comment: Im pretty sure that my answer above is what you need.  Simply move all of your for loop logic into the callback to $q.all and you will have all the data available in one place.